# Artfifactory show users that downloaded file

Tags: artifactory

I want to find out which users have downloaded a file from Artifactory. Actually, I only see the user that performed the last download in the Artifactory "GUI". I tried to find a corresponding resource in the REST API but wasn't able to find one.

My question: Does Artifactory offer a web API to find out which users have downloaded a specific file?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no UI for your requested behavior in Artifactory.

You can look at the "request.log" located in `$ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs` and search for the requested file, there you will see all users that requested this file (please note that all log files have rotation enabled, so you will have more than one "request.log").

Example of a log entry of downloading a file:
`20180115190621|48|REQUEST|10.0.0.1|admin|GET|/generic-local/demo_copy.key|HTTP/1.1|200|3272`

Hope this helps!