# Determine downstream consumers of Artifactory Package

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

How to determine all the downstream consumers of a package in artifactory?

We have a lot of applications and our vulnerability scan is generating a list of packages which are unsafe. We wish to inform the consumers without having to go through each of the services list of dependencies. Can we automate this somehow?

EDIT: I do not need need to know the exact user that pulled a repo, rather an application which consumed it. For example, this might be a stretch but can we set some headers in our request to artifactory in which it can probably parse the headers and persist that service xyz requested package abc at 123 time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artfifactory show users that downloaded file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387376/artfifactory-show-users-that-downloaded-file)

Answer (score 0):

If the builds that later use this package as a dependency state this in the **[BuildInfo](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration)** which is published to Artifactory, you should see this in Artifactory (Even in the UI).
If you would use JFrog Xray for vulnerability scanning, it provides a bigger picture of all builds and other products that use this package.